# Position of layer during CAKeyFrameAnimation remains constant

Tags: ios, swift, cakeyframeanimation

I am animating the layer of a UIView subclass along a path. When I print the position of the layer it always returns the same value, the position of the view itself.

How can I access the position during animation? Or should I use spritekit for this?

Comment: Hmm, not an exact match... Key point is: use the `presentationLayer`

Comment: Thanks, that answer solved it